# Cleaning up Census Bureau data frames

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to clean up and manipulate data frames of Census Bureau data. I am using (for loop) in R to do it but this is taking more than 20 hours so far!!

The problem is that I'm using two different data frames

This is my code

```
t=1
for(i in 1:25558){ # number of records in the Housing record

family <- array(0,dim=c(0,12)) # creating an empty array to store row number

k=1
n=0
for(j in t:52608){  # number of records in the Personal record
   if(Housing[i,5] == Personal[j,2]) {
     family[k]=j
     k=k+1
     n=1
     }
   else( 
    if(n == 1) {
      t=j
      break
     }
    )
}

a=0 
for(m in 1:length(family)){
    if(is.na(Personal[family[m],22])) {  # Some families has mix values: NA and numbers
      break
      }

 else( 
     if(Personal[family[m],22] > 1){
     a=a+1
     }
     )
  }

 if(a == length(family)) {
     Housing[i,1]=1
    }

}
```

(EDIT - an example):
In the Hosing record, I have an ID for each family. In the personal record, the same family ID is repeated for all family members.

```
Housing Record:
ID  Family Ability to Speak English
1             0
2             0
3             1



Personal Record:
ID  Member  Person Ability to Speak English
1     1                    1
1     2                    NA
1     3                    2
2     1                    4
2     2                    1
3     1                    3
3     2                    2
```

Note: "NA" here does not mean "Not Available", it has a specific meaning (basically I should not remove it)

I need to change the value of the column "Family Ability to Speak English" to 1 based on that family members ability to speak English. (see the last part of my code)

Comment: Please provide some example showing the structure of your data, and describe what the output should look like after "clean up."

Comment: Hi Won, I put an example,, Thanks

Comment: Could you explain in words what is your rule for assigning 0 as opposed to 1? The loops have plenty of moving pieces and are hard to follow. Also, `Personal[family[m],22]` does not match anything in your example.

Comment: Your given data doesn't make it clear how the family ability column is determined. Family 2 has two members with positive scores, but the family ability column is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# some dummy data frame for families
family <- data.frame(famid=rep(1:5, each=3), 
                     member=rep(1:3, 5), 
                     speake=sample(c(1:4, NA, NA), 15, replace=TRUE))

# a function to calculate scores 
# (modify according to your scoring algorithm)
english_score <- function(fam){
    # pull out the English scores for all members of fam
    data <- family$speake[which(family$famid==fam)]
    # I dont know how you want to number the families,
    # by their combined English score, or just if any exist
    # so demonstrate both
    eng_sum <- sum(na.omit(data))
    eng_present <- !any(is.na(data))

    #return this result of the function as a vector
    c(fam, eng_sum, eng_present)
}

# apply the function to each unique family
housing <- sapply(unique(family$famid), english_score)
housing <- as.data.frame(t(housing))
colnames(housing) <- c("family", "eng_sum", "eng_present")
```

Comment: ok the way I wrote it is not giving "is english present" but "does everybody speak english"

Comment: It would be great if you select this as the correct answer, using the checkmark.